# Order Confirmation page

Tags: expresso-store

I have an Exp:resso store setup based off of the example templates bundled with the software. I'm using Stripe.com as my payment gateway, in test mode.

#### Problem:

After submitting a payment, checkout page 3 returns to itself without proceeding to the return="shop/order/ORDER_HASH".

[This is the response](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/161736/screen%20grab%202013-04-15%20at%2011.22.44%20PM.PNG) that I see in my Stripe control panel.

`The site is available at: http://74.52.63.240/shop/product/alessandra`
(sorry, stackexchange won't link to an IP address)

There is an SSL cert installed for https://taliahancock.com. For testing purposes, I have my hosts file set to 74.52.63.240 taliahancock.com.

Help is much appreciated. This is my first time using both Exp:resso store and Stripe.

Comment: What javascript are you using to submit the Stripe payment? When you put `{error:payment_method}` in your template what does it show?

Comment: The script that I'm using is too long to post in a comment here, it's at the very bottom of the checkout3 page. [Here's a link to it.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/161736/stripe_submit.js)

Comment: I have the `{error:payment_method}` tag in the checkout3 template, but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: I've turned off the require SSL option in the store now, so you can view the checkout without having to be on the domain name. This doesn't seem to solve any of the return problems though.

Comment: Can you try removing `error_handling="inline"` from your final checkout tag? I think there must be an error message which is not being displayed.

Comment: I removed `error_handling="inline"` on the checkout3 template, I'm still not seeing any error reports.

Comment: If it helps, this is [the checkout template](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/161736/checkout3.html) as I have it.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Adrian. Anything else you can think of trying? I'm going to need to launch this site soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit the order, your "Place Order" button needs to have `name="submit"` attached to it. This is so that Store can distinguish it from simply an "Update Totals" button, or a "Next Step" button. Currently it's being treated as an "Update Totals" button.

For example, in your checkout template, change:

```
<button id="checkout_submit">Place Order</button>
```

to:

```
<button id="checkout_submit" name="submit">Place Order</button>
```

or alternatively:

```
<input type="submit" id="checkout_submit" name="submit" value="Place Order" />
```

Documentation here: https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#submitting_orders

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well.  I'm using commit instead of submit as mentioned in your docs. Is there anything else that wouldn't allow it to redirect?  

`<input type="submit" name="commit" class="button large left place-order" value="Place Order" />`

Comment: If it's still not redirecting, it means there is an error on the page which isn't displaying. Try removing `error_handling="inline"` from your checkout tag.