# checkout return param doesn't get honoured on submit

Tags: expresso-store

Trying to submit an order, though I can't seem to get it to forward to the return path.

Here's my tag:

```
{exp:store:checkout require="name|address1|state|country|postcode|order_email" return="/checkout/order-complete/ORDER_HASH" form_class="form"}
```

I've seen this post, and it behaves exactly the same, though I do have a name attribute set & that doesn't make a difference :(

[Order Confirmation page](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/order-confirmation-page)

Tried both a button element & an input (like the docs use) no difference...

`<button class="cta" type="submit" name="submit">Pay Now</button>`

Seems like my post request is 302ing...

[image: post request 302s]

Seems like the params are set twice in my post data? Maybe it's being overwritten?

[image: post data from the 302]

I've tried this with both relative & absolute paths in the return param on the checkout tag. No difference. The order gets submitted, cart gets emptied and it reloads the page /checkout/review-and-pay.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors on the page you are leaving? Presumably that’s the `/review-and-pay/` template, and it might be sending you back because of unhanded errors.

Comment: That was it! didn't have `{error:payment_method}` on the page & it was trying to tell me something is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't have {error:payment_method} on the page & it was trying to tell me something is up.

Answer (score 0):

Always check for errors; turn inline error handling off first (for a quick test) then turn inline back on and ensure you have error handling on (every required field, etc). A return to a page usually indicates an unhandled form error.